# Pandas Dataframe to rank every 2 increment values in a column with groupby another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column name of "Months" and "R", with the values of:

| Months | R |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11 | 1 |
| 2020-11 | 2 |
| 2020-11 | 3 |
| 2020-11 | 4 |
| 2020-11 | 5 |
| 2020-11 | 6 |
| 2020-10 | 1 |
| 2020-10 | 2 |
| 2020-10 | 3 |
| 2020-10 | 4 |
| 2020-12 | 1 |
| 2020-12 | 2 |
| 2020-12 | 3 |
| 2020-12 | 4 |
| 2020-12 | 5 |
| 2020-12 | 6 |
| 2020-12 | 7 |

How do I apply a rank function on every 2 increment values in the "R" column with a group by function on "Months" column.

Desired outcome should be like this :

| Months | R | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-11 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-11 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-11 | 4 | 2 |
| 2020-11 | 5 | 3 |
| 2020-11 | 6 | 3 |
| 2020-10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-10 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-10 | 4 | 2 |
| 2020-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-12 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-12 | 4 | 2 |
| 2020-12 | 5 | 3 |
| 2020-12 | 6 | 3 |
| 2020-12 | 7 | 4 |

Comment: What should be the output if I remove  `|2020-11 | 4 | 2 |` this row. does the next one will have `|2020-11 | 5 | 2|` ?? instead of `|2020-11 | 5 | 3 |`

Comment: Can you add more test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cumcount` if you want to group 2 consecutive values together and then rank them after grouping first by `Month`. Assuming you have sorted values.

**df:**

```
    Months  R
0   2020-11 1
1   2020-11 2
2   2020-11 5
3   2020-11 6
4   2020-10 1
5   2020-10 2
6   2020-10 3
7   2020-10 4
8   2020-12 1
9   2020-12 2
10  2020-12 3
11  2020-12 4
12  2020-12 5
13  2020-12 6
14  2020-12 7
```

---

```
df['rank'] = (df.groupby(['Months']).cumcount()//2).rank(method='dense', ascending=True).astype(int)
```

**df:**

```
    Months  R   rank
0   2020-11 1   1
1   2020-11 2   1
2   2020-11 5   2
3   2020-11 6   2
4   2020-10 1   1
5   2020-10 2   1
6   2020-10 3   2
7   2020-10 4   2
8   2020-12 1   1
9   2020-12 2   1
10  2020-12 3   2
11  2020-12 4   2
12  2020-12 5   3
13  2020-12 6   3
14  2020-12 7   4
```

Comment: hi @pygirl, thanks for your solution. This is what i'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Can you close the question by accepting this as an answer if it helps :)